Work in an electrochemical system
Good day guys,
I was looking at Bard's book on Electrochemical Methods, in Chapter two the change in Gibbs energy for a reaction is given by:
$$\Delta G = -nFE_{rxn}$$
This explanation is consistent with the one given in Thermal Physics by Schroeder:
$$\Delta G = W^{rev}_{electric}$$
Bard's book writes the nernst equation as:
$$E_{rxn} = E^0_{rxn}+\frac{RT}{nF}ln\frac{C_O}{C_R}$$
However, I have seen derivations of the Nernst Equation that use the definition of electrochemical potential:
$$\mu' = \mu^0 +RTln(a_i) + z_iF\phi$$
They take the condition of electrochemical equilibrium:
$$\Delta G = \sum_{Prod} s_i\mu'-\sum_{React} s_i\mu' = 0$$
They solve for the potential difference between phases to arrive to this form of the Nernst equation:
$$\Delta \phi = \Delta \phi^0+\frac{RT}{nF}ln\frac{a_O}{a_R} $$
To me it is not clear why one approach considers $\Delta G = 0$ while the other one does not and both are supposed to describe the system's equilibrium potential.
I can only understand this with the following interpretation:
$\Delta G$ is taken as $\sum_P \mu_i n_i - \sum_R \mu_i n_i$, where $\mu_i$ is the chemical potential. When this approach is taken, for a reversible process: $\Delta G$ the change in chemical potential corresponds to electric work. Using Faraday's law we can express the electric work as $-nFE$, where E is the reversible (equilibrium) potential. We can solve for E and obtain Nernst's Equation.
The second approach redefines $\Delta G$, and is taken as $\sum_P \mu'_i n_i - \sum_R \mu'_i n_i$, where $\mu'_i$ is the electrochemical potential.
Assuming electrochemical equilibrium, the new $\Delta G$ is zero and we can solve for the equilibrium potential, obtaining Nernst's equation.

The problem of the question is due to a confusion of  Δ  and  Δ°. I will not develop this theory now. It is elementary. Please read good books in thermodynamics !

I do not have any confusion between those quantities, please let me how I can improve the question!

At equilibrium DeltaG=0 and E=0. What is your question?

At electrochemical equilibrium $\Delta G = 0 $, so we can solve for the potential difference $\Delta \phi = \phi_S - \phi_M $ and obtain the Nernst Equation for the equilibrium potential between an electrode and the solution as written above. I have seen this procedure done in Hamman's electrochemistry book, as well as Analytical and Physical electrochemistry by Girault. They sablish at that point there is zero current, but they describe a non zero potential, given by the Nernst equation. I can cite the pages if needed. Thank you for the feedback.

Cross posted at Physics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/830850/44126

The main issue here is the distinction between the cell reaction and a
single-electrode (half) reaction. Bard's use of subscript rxn is always for
a cell reaction; I do not see that he writes the Nernst equation for $E_{rxn}
$ (for a cell) with the ratio of concentrations $C_{\mathrm{O}}/C_{\mathrm{R}
}$ (for a half reaction).
When we talk about the reversible work for a cell, the $\Delta G=\Delta
G_{rxn}$ is for the cell reaction and $E_{rxn}$ is the cell potential. Each
half reaction is at equilibrium across its own interface, but the cell
reaction is not at equilibrium, and $\Delta G_{rxn}=-nFE_{rxn}\neq 0$.
The derivations of the Nernst equation in terms of the electrochemical
potentials are usually (as here in the post) for half reactions for which
the (electrochemical) $\Delta G$ is zero, as appropriate for equilibrium
across the interface. Then $\Delta \phi $ is the potential difference
between the metal and the solution at that interface. One can then combine
the two Nernst equations at each electrode to get the cell Nernst equation.
(Bard does this in sec. 2.2.4(d) (first edition), "Formulation of a cell
potential".)
